# Is there a good way to secure access to an entire staging server?

Tags: security, apache-2.2

I have a staging server and production server that hosts multiple sites (using Apache2.2). Currently, I have the DNS pointing `stage.domainX.com` to the staging server and `*.domainX.com` pointing to the production server.

Everything seems to be working pretty good, but I would like to be able to secure the access to the staging server. So, unless it is the right person, someone trying to enter `stage.domainX.com` should be disallowed (and, if possible, go to the production server).

And, I wanted to use a domain name instead of an IP because I want the clients to be able to more friendly view the staging site (instead of memorizing an IP address).

Is there a good way to handle this? Or, am I handling the staging domain name process in an unusual way?

P.S. I've actually wanted to manage this through ports, but I haven't figured out a way to do it. Like, domainX.com:80 (standard) goes to production and domainX.com:9000 goes to staging. Haven't found a way to do this in DNS though (using GoDaddy's nameservers/zones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Apache you can simply set up your staging server's `Allow` and `Deny` directives to restrict access to authorized IP addresses.  Alternatively you can put the entire thing behind HTTP Authentication (username/password, or client certificates if you want to get really fancy).
Bonus points for using a custom "unauthorized" error page to redirect people to the production site .

Configuring Apache to serve the staging site on a different port is also an option, but this is just "security through obscurity" like using the `stage.domainX.com` domain -- it doesn't stop anyone from finding the staging site if they go looking.

<rant>
Note that changing the port **IS NOT** something you do with DNS - it's a webserver configuration thing (See the Apache manual for details). DNS has **NO CONCEPT** of port numbers, it's just a name-to-IP (or IP-to-name) mapping* -- pet peeve.
* There are some limited exceptions, like SRV records, but we're talking about **A**ddress and **CNAME** records
</rant>

Comment: Thanks for the help. Right, DNS does not handle ports - that makes sense. But, that means every instance of `domainX.com:<port>` will go to the same server. How do you configure a domain to go to different physical servers (not just vhosts) based on the port used?

Comment: @Steve two real options -- run two copies of your web stack (Apache all the way on down through your database) on different ports, or put in a load-balancer box that does the actual listening (and redirects to the appropriate real machine based on port) -- Honestly a staging domain with access control is probably better, especially if you're smart enough to use two separate servers :)

Answer (score 3):

I've used an Apache setup like the following successfully in the past; it allows certain listed IP-addresses to freely access the staging site without supplying Basic-Authentication credentials (e.g. you could add the IP-addresses of your-office and your-client's-office), but still allows for password-based access if the client is out-of-office, for example.

```
# Set NOAUTH environment-variable for certain IPs that are allowed without credentials
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr 11.22.33.44 NOAUTH=1

# Staging
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    stage.domainX.com
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/stage.domainX.com

    # Access restrictions
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        # Anyone with the NOAUTH environment variable is allowed
        Allow from env=NOAUTH

        # Anyone that has valid credentials is allowed
        AuthType      Basic
        AuthName      "DomainX Staging"
        AuthUserFile  /etc/apache2/staging.domainX.com.passwd
        Require valid-user

        # Either of the above is fine
        Satisfy Any
    </Location>

    # ... other directives ...
</VirtualHost>

# Production
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    domainX.com
    DocumentRoot  /var/www/domainX.com

    # ... other directives ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked great.  Note to anyone who tries to use this... create a password file with `htpasswd` command.